# How to not duplicate calendar appointments?

Tags: vba, outlook

I found VBA code that checks my schedule and creates an all-day 'busy' appointment if I exceed a certain amount of time in meetings on a given day.

The code works, but creates a duplicate event each time it runs.

I want to add a condition to see if an event already exists with the subject line "%hours of appt today" to prevent duplicate calendar events.

```vb
Sub BlockMoreCalendarAppts()
 
Dim myAcct As Outlook.Recipient
Dim myFB As String
Dim tDate As Date
Dim d As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim test As String
Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem

' it needs to know whose FB to check. Set this as your email address
Set myAcct = Session.CreateRecipient("myemailaddress")

' days to check (checks calendar for (7) days from todays date)
For d = 0 To 7
    tDate = Date + d

    ' use start of working day or there about
    ' false counts tenetive and oof as busy
    myFB = myAcct.FreeBusy(tDate + #7:30:00 AM#, 5, False)

    ' this gets the # of 5 min periods before the start time
    i = (TimeValue(tDate + #7:30:00 AM#) * 288)

    ' only count free busy for 9 hours from start + at least 1 additional 5 min period
    ' (in my example, my day starts at 7:30 and ends at 4:30, so counting 9 hours)
    ' # of min in working day / 5
    ' skips busy times in the evening
    test = Mid(myFB, i, 545 / 5)

    CountOccurrences = UBound(Split(test, "1")) 'busy, oof or tentative

    CountO = UBound(Split(test, "0")) ' free

    'round to hours for subject
    times = Round(((CountOccurrences * 5) / 60), 2)

    ' create all day busy event when I am scheduled
    ' to be in meetings for 5 or more hours per day
    ' there are 12 5 minute periods per hour
    ' 60 = 5 hours, 48 = 4 hours, 72 = 6 hours
    If CountOccurrences >= 60 Then

        ' check to make sure an all day event wasn't already created
        ' to mark a day as busy



        ' default calendar
        Set oAppt = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
        With oAppt
            .Subject = times & " hours of appt today"
            .Start = tDate
            .ReminderSet = False
            .Categories = "Full Day"
            .AllDayEvent = True
            .BusyStatus = olBusy
            .Save
        End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to search for appointments on a specific date and with a specific subject.

```
Public objCalendar As Outlook.folder
Public CalendarItems As Outlook.Items
Public oAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Function Calendar_ApptExists(appt_Date As Date, appt_subject$) As Boolean

    Set objCalendar = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set CalendarItems = objCalendar.Items
    
    ' Items in calendar
    Debug.Print "Items in Calendar: " & CalendarItems.Count
        
    ' Search calendar
    For Each oAppt In CalendarItems
        Debug.Print oAppt.Start, oAppt.Subject
        
        ' Check is appointment already exists
        If (Int(oAppt.Start) = appt_Date) And oAppt.Subject = appt_subject Then
            MsgBox "Already exists an appointment with '" & oAppt.Subject & "'", vbExclamation
            Calendar_ApptExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Iterating over all items in the calendar is not really a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

> The code works, but creates a duplicate event each time it runs.

That is because in the code you create a new appointment item:

```
        ' default calendar
        Set oAppt = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
        With oAppt
            .Subject = times & " hours of appt today"
            .Start = tDate
            .ReminderSet = False
            .Categories = "Full Day"
            .AllDayEvent = True
            .BusyStatus = olBusy
            .Save
        End With
```

Instead, you need to use `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class to find any appointment for the specified time frame. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)